# SSH error: ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.x.x port 22: DH GEX group out of range

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem with SSH. I can not ssh into a server because of DH GEX group out of range

My ssh version:

> OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

I tried to ssh into a server that has host key algorithms:

```
c-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64 @openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hma c-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 mac algo SC: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@open ssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm @openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md 5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com ,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1
-96,hmac-md5-96 comp algo CS: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib comp algo SC: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
```

And this is my ssh debug:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/haniz/.ssh/config
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug2: resolving "192.168.150.136" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.150.136 [192.168.150.136] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/haniz/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/haniz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/haniz/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/haniz/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/haniz/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/haniz/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/haniz/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/haniz/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version ROSSSH
debug1: no match: ROSSSH
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.150.136:22 as 'haniz'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-dss
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.150.136 port 22: DH GEX group out of range
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Update the Mikrotik's firmware?

Comment: No, I just have tried to ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible solutions to the issue.

1. At the client end you should upgrade new openssh7.2p
2. Modify /etc/ssh/module (client end)

From origin to Target:

If you want to connect to deprecated server from new open ssh server through ssh. Just try the below command

```
ssh -v -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss my.linux.com
```

Comment: I tried to connect to the server without modify or upgrade that server, I tried some attemps like that you recommended. But It doesn't work! Do you have more ideas?

Comment: Can I downgrade my ssh version?

Comment: Can you provide what error have you seen while executing above coomand so that it could be helpful for me further debugging.        In my case it's working fine

Comment: May you explain how it work and how to re-config it to run without your above command?